# Set unlimited width CSS

Tags: css

I have been tasked with making an update to the following site:

http://www.sandysharkey.com/

I would like it to allow an infinite number of images to appear horizontally in each category.  You will see right now that the width is hard set in the CSS, which isn't ideal as the image will start tiling underneath each other if they reach that width.

Any tips on how I can modify the CSS to allow for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried removing all css width references and adding a max-height reference?

Comment: Yes, this doesn't seem to do the trick.  Images all bunch up underneath one another then.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `white-space: nowrap;` ?

Comment: How do I use it?  I tried removing the width:32570px; in the .main class, and adding in white-space: nowrap;  This didn't have the desired effect though.

Comment: That along with a width: 100%   Still no go.

Comment: Can anyone explain how to use this solution properly?

Comment: Anyone?  Still a no go.

Answer (score 1):

Set

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

on the image container element. Also add `display: inline-block;` to your images if you didn't already (or `inline`).

You should consider using some kind of slider script. People don't like horizontal scrollbars

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  I've added white-space: nowrap; to the classes main and banner_sec, and added display: inline-block; to each img tag.

Comment: When I remove the width on the .main container all the images tile underneath one another again.

Comment: @user1110562: I've merged your repost into your original question so you'll have to accept this answer a second time. In future, please don't repost questions.

Answer (score 1):

There is a jquery solution I have created, which allows you to add as many images as you like, and it will adjust the width of the image container dynamically. See here - http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/zovbe

For a CSS only solution, you would create a container for the image container. The image container would be auto width, the outer container would have overflow-x set to auto. This css can be viewed in the above demo too.

hope this helps